# Using Ruby to upload files to Sharepoint 2003

Tags: ruby, sharepoint

Disclaimer: My Sharepoint knowledge is slim, and my Ruby knowledge is novice-moderate.

I need to be able to programmatically upload files to a Sharepoint server.  So far, I've been looking into the Savon gem (patched to add NTLM auth) to accomplish this.

Sample code so far:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'savon'

WSDL_URL = 'http://<server removed>/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl'
SP_USERNAME = 'user'
SP_PASSWORD = 'password'

client = Savon::Client.new(WSDL_URL)
client.request.ntlm_auth(SP_USERNAME, SP_PASSWORD)
puts client.wsdl.soap_actions
```

This all works fine, but I'm at a loss where to go next in order to upload files.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to upload/download files to/from SharePoint you don't need the Web Services

To upload just use HTTP PUT requests.
Here is an example in C# [Uploading Files to SharePoint Server 2007 from ASP.NET Web Applications by Using the HTTP PUT Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd902097.aspx)

To download just use HTTP GET requests

Comment: Thanks for your response.  However, can go into more detail about how to accomplish that?  Sorry if it seems like a simple answer, but I've focused my efforts solely into using web services, so I'm not sure how to interact with a Sharepoint server directly using HTTP requests.

Comment: I have no Ruby knowledge, but have added a link to a c# example in my reply above